# Riverpod: StateProvider is not updated

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I have 2 providers.
The one that deals with selected filters:

```
final filtersProvider = StateProvider.autoDispose<List<String>>(
  (ref) => [],
);
```

And the other that receives data.
It's observes the filters value.

```
final priceResponseProvider =
    FutureProvider.autoDispose.family<PriceResponse, GetPriceParams>(
  (ref, params) {

    // This should update [priceResponseProvider] 
    // every time when [filtersProvider] changes.
    // But it does not 
    final filters = ref.watch(filtersProvider);
    return ref
        .read(priceFetcherProvider)
        .search(params.copyWith(filterBrands: filters));
  },
);
```

Besides I have 2 screens.

1. PricePage is responsible for presenting results.

```
class PricePage extends ConsumerWidget {
  const PricePage({required this.params, super.key});

  static void navigate(
    BuildContext context, {
    required GetPriceParams params,
  }) =>
      context.pushNamed(name, extra: params);

  final GetPriceParams params;
  static const name = 'price_page';
  static const path = '/price_page';


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final searchResult = ref.watch(priceResponseProvider(params));

    return Scaffold(
      body: searchResult.when(
        loading: () => const LoadingWidget(),
        error: (e, __) => Text((e as CustomException).message ?? ''),
        data: (PriceResponse resp) {

          final titles = resp.result.map((e) => e.caption).toList();
          final items = ref.watch(priceGroupsProvider(resp));

          return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBarWidget(
              title: _title,
              image: AppImages.filter,
              onTap: () async {
                // Navigates to PriceFiltersPage and returns selected filters
                final filters = await PriceFiltersPage.navigate(
                  context,
                  model: PriceFiltersPageModel(
                    brands: resp.brands.map((e) => e.brand).toList(),
                    initialSelected: ref.read(filtersProvider),
                  ),
                );

                if (filters == null) return;

                // Updates provider with selected filters
                ref.read(filtersProvider.notifier).state = filters;
              },
            ),
            body: PriceListView(items: items)
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

2. PriceFiltersPage is responsible for selecting  results.

```
class PriceFiltersPageModel {
  PriceFiltersPageModel({
    required this.brands,
    required this.initialSelected,
  });

  final List<String> brands;
  final List<String> initialSelected;
}

class PriceFiltersPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const PriceFiltersPage({required this.model, super.key});

  static const String name = 'price_filters';
  static const String path = '/price_filters';
  final PriceFiltersPageModel model;

  static Future<List<String>?> navigate(
    BuildContext context, {
    required PriceFiltersPageModel model,
  }) async =>
      context.pushNamed(name, extra: model);

  @override
  State<PriceFiltersPage> createState() => _PriceFiltersPageState();
}

class _PriceFiltersPageState extends State<PriceFiltersPage> {
  late List<String> selected = widget.model.initialSelected;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBarWidget(
        title: 'Фильтры',
        stageText: 'Сбросить',
        onLeadingButtonTap: () {},
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: AppDecoration.padding,
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 24, bottom: 90),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      _TitleWidget(
                        title: 'Бренд',
                        onResetTap: () {},
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(height: 12),
                      FiltersChoiceChipWidget(
                        titles: widget.model.brands,
                        initialSelectedValues: widget.model.initialSelected,
                        onSelectedValues: (values) {
                          selected = values;
                        },
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              // КНОПКА ПРИМЕНИТЬ
              Positioned(
                left: 16,
                right: 16,
                bottom: 20,
                child: MainButton(
                  title: 'Применить',
                  onTap: () {

                    // returns selected filters

                    context.pop(selected);
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I want to update priceResponseProvider every time when filtersProvider changes.
However for some reason it does not executes when I change value filtersProvider.

I tried to to assign filtersProvider inside PriceFiltersPage, the same result.
I also tries to listen to filtersProvider updates inside the PricePage but the listener does not executes.

Appreciate any help

Comment: The literature is rushing to catch up with Remi's prolific development.  In brief, avoid legacy ChangeNotifier, StateNotifier (and their providers) and StateProvider.  Use only Provider, FutureProvider, StreamProvider, and Notifier, AsyncNotifier, StreamNotifier (and their providers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You passed the result of `ref.read(filtersProvider)` to `PriceFiltersPage`, which is a `List<String>`, and the page return the same `List` even though the elements might have been modified. Riverpod doesn't know those changes since the `List` refers to the same `List` that the provider previously has. Although this might not be the best practice, but as a quick fix you can pass your list to the page like this:

```dart
final filters = await PriceFiltersPage.navigate(
  context,
  model: PriceFiltersPageModel(
    brands: resp.brands.map((e) => e.brand).toList(),
    initialSelected: [...ref.read(filtersProvider)],
  ),
);
```

Please see the [`StateNotifierProvider`](https://riverpod.dev/docs/providers/state_notifier_provider) documentation for the good practice on how to handle list in a provider.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However PriceFiltersPage returns selected filters correctly. 
The only problem I face is that the filtersProvider is not updated when I try to apply changes

Comment: Can you confirm if my solution worked or not though? @AngelinaGromova

Comment: But you did not provided any solution for the existing problem.
Maybe you did not fully understand the issue?
I didn't have any issues with returning data from PriceFiltersPage.

Comment: Instead of your way to pass the list: `initialSelected: ref.read(filtersProvider)`, I changed it to this: `initialSelected: [...ref.read(filtersProvider)]` to make sure the returned list is a different list and that way Riverpod will know that the list has changed (it's not a good practice but might work, so I need your confirmation) @AngelinaGromova

Comment: In other words, no matter how much you modify the list, Riverpod won't be able to know the changes since the `List` is still technically the same. You can see that it returns the selected filters correctly, but Riverpod doesn't know that it has changed. That is the reason why your provider isn't rebuilding and the listener doesn't work. With my quick fix, it should at least work now

Comment: Sorry for my misunderstanding. You solution worked like a charm. Thank you so much